# Rails 4 Select Menu action cannot be nil error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to use the Rails form_for and collection select tags to populate a select menu from a database table.  When the user hits the submit button there selection will be reflected in my shopping cat table (through the join table CampaignItems).  Currently I'm getting a:

```
First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty error
```

The view is in my store **`index.html.erb`** file.

Here is my view:

```
<% form_for @duration do |f| %>
    <%= f.collection_select :duration, Duration.all, :id, :name %>
    <%= f.submit 'Submit', campaign_items_path(duration_id: duration) %> 
<% end %>
```

My Durations controller:

```
def index
    @durations = Duration.all
end
def new
    @duration = Duration.new
end
```

My Store Controller:

```
def index
   @products = Product.order(:title)
   @cart= current_cart
   @durations = Duration.all
 end
```

Comment: Please format your post, it's incomprehensible now.

Comment: Sorry this is my first post, is that better?

Comment: Yes, welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: @user3738181 What exactly are you trying to achieve from that form? Create a `duration` record, or add a duration to campaign, or add a product record etc? We can help you better if you could explain that.

Comment: @KirtiThorat I'm trying to add a duration, a duration is going to be like (1 month, 2 month...) and then there is a value  associated with that that I want to add to my shopping cart, but I was going to use campaign_items as a foreign key linking my shopping cart to my durations table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty error

The problem is you have declared **`@durations = Duration.all`** in your **`index action`**,but you are using **`@duration`** in the **`form`**.You should be using **`@durations`**.

It should be like this

```
<% form_for @durations do |f| %>
<%= f.collection_select :duration, Duration.all, :id, :name %
<%= f.submit 'Submit', campaign_items_path(duration_id: duration) %> 
<% end %>
```